# Retrieve Custom Object From Hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I've written a PowerShell function to create a custom object and stores it into a hashtable. The issue I'm facing is retrieving that object. I need to retrieve that object because it contains an array, I need to loop through that array and write it to a text file.

```psh
function removeItem {
    <#Madatory Parameters for function, it takes the path to the files/folders
    to clean up and path to the hashtable.#>
    Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$path,
        [string]$writetoText,
        [hashtable] $hashWrite=@{}
    )

    <#Begin if statement: Test if Path Exists#>
    if (Test-Path ($path)) {
        <#Begin if statement: Check if file is Directory#>
        if ((Get-Item $path) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
            $pathObj = [pscustomobject]@{
                pathName = $path
                Wipe = (Get-ChildItem -Path  $path -Recurse)
                Count = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Measure-Object).Count
            }

            # Write-Output $pathObj.Wipe

            #Add Data to Hashtable
            $hashWrite.Add($pathObj.pathName,$pathObj)

            foreach ($h in $hashWrite.GetEnumerator()) {
                Write-Host "$($h.Name): $($h.Value)"
            }

            <#
            [string[]]$view = $pathObj.Wipe
            for ($i=0; $i -le $view.Count; $i++){
                Write-Output $view[$i]
            }
            #>

            $pathObj.pathName = $pathObj.pathName + "*"
        }<#End if statement:Check if file is Directory #> 
    }       
}
```

My function takes 3 arguments, a path, the text file path, and a hashtable. Now, I create a custom object and store the path, files/folders contained in that path, and the count. Now, my issue is, I want to retrieve that custom object from my hashtable so that I can loop though the `Wipe` variable, because it's an array, and write it to the text file. If I print the hashtable to the screen it see the `Wipe` variable as `System.Object[]`.

How do I retrieve my custom object from the hash table so I can loop through the `Wipe` Variable?

Possible Solution:

```psh
$pathObj = [pscustomobject]@{
    pathName = $path
    Wipe = (Get-ChildItem -Path  $path -Recurse)
    Count = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Measure-Object).Count
}

#Add Data to Hashtable
$hashWrite.Add($pathObj.pathName,$pathObj)

foreach ($h in $hashWrite.GetEnumerator()) {
    $read= $h.Value

    [string[]]$view = $read.Wipe
    for ($i=0; $i -le $view.Count; $i++) {
        Write-Output $view[$i]
    }
}
```

Is this the ideal way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are uses for `GetEnumerator()`, but in your case you're better off just looping over the keys of the hashtable:

```psh
$hashWrite.Keys | % {
  $hashWrite[$_].Wipe
} | select -Expand FullName
```